# Angular 5 Subject Observer in child route component cannot be cached by parent route component

Tags: angular, routes, observable

So I am working on angular 5,,, using child routes like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'inbox', component: InboxComponent,
    children: [
      { path: ':id', component: RequestDetailsComponent }
    ]
  },

  { path: '', redirectTo: '/inbox', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: InboxComponent }

];
```

basically I want to change something in the Inbox component if I loaded the rout 'inbox/id'... so I want the  inbox component to do some action,, and when I click on a button on the details component,, I want to change the parent route..lets assume that the change is a html class addition - removing..

I used Subject to observe the change ,,by creating a service,, Inbox service,, as follows:

```
mport { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { ApiHelperService } from "../../shared/services/api-helper.service";
import { Subject } from "rxjs/Subject";
import { Question } from "../../models/question";

@Injectable()
export class InboxService {
    uri = 'questions?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&filter=!-*f(6rLIPlIq';
    colors = ['bg-primary-400', 'bg-purple-400', 'bg-info-400', 'bg-warning-400', 'bg-danger-400', 'bg-violet-400', 'bg-success-400'];
    public  openRequestDetails = new Subject<number>();

    changeView(view: number){
        this.openRequestDetails.next(view);
    }
}
```

In my RequestDetailsComponent I am calling the change view function in the service like this :

```
  onChangeView() {
    this.inboxService.changeView(this.mode);
  }
```

and in my InboxCompnent I am subscribing to the subject like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-inbox',
  templateUrl: './inbox.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./inbox.component.scss'],
  providers: [InboxService]
})
export class InboxComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private subscription: Subscription;
 ngOnInit() {
        this.subscription = this.inboxService.openRequestDetails
          .subscribe(
          (request: any) => {
            console.log(request);
          },
          (error: any) => console.log('error'),
          () => console.log('complete')
        )
}
```

For the reference,, here is my app.module,, I'be deleted the irrelevant imports:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { InboxComponent } from './inbox/inbox.component';
import { RequestComponent } from './inbox/request/request.component';
import { RequestDetailsComponent } from './inbox/request-details/request-details.component';
import { InboxService } from './inbox/inbox.service';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './routing/app-routing.module';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    InboxComponent,
    RequestComponent,
    RequestDetailsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [ApiHelperService, InboxService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

***At the end,this subscription never fires when I am at the child route inbox/123...***

any Idea???   And I cannot use child component,, it has to be child route.. because I'll have many child routes.

If i Added the subscription in the same component RequestDetailsComponent.. it works fine..

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and the root of the problem was in the DI of the service. Do you inject `InboxService` in the shared module that includes all those components ? Check your `providers` array of the module - you haven't shared it here yet.

Comment: the inbox service is injected correctly every where,, I am using to read data from APIs.  and the next function is called,, but the inboxComponent (the parent component) is not catching the event

Comment: I've updated my question with more code for your reference